What variables are destroyed when calling exit(), based on Microsoft's docs?
I was trying to figure out the differences between terminate(), exit() and abort(), and Microsoft's
C++ program termination documentation came up in my Google search that compares exit vs abort vs atexit.
I read the first part that compares exit and abort, and it makes sense:

The difference between exit and abort is that exit allows the C++
runtime termination processing to take place (global object destructors get called). abort terminates the program immediately. The abort function bypasses the normal destruction process for initialized global static objects. It also bypasses any special processing that was specified using the atexit function.

Then later, there is a comparison of return and exit with this sample code and corresponding explanation:
// return_statement.cpp
#include <stdlib.h>

struct S 
{
    int value;
};

int main()
{
    S s{ 3 };

    exit( 3 );
    // or
    return 3;
}


The exit and return statements in the preceding example have similar behavior. Both terminate the program and return a value of 3 to the operating system. The difference is that exit doesn't destroy the automatic variable s, while the return statement does.


I thought that s would also be destroyed when exit() is called. Did I misunderstand, or is there a mistake?

If s isn't destroyed, how do we reclaim this memory from the stack? What if s were on the heap, would we have leaked this memory, too?


I am not looking for Microsoft-specific solutions. I just found the source and realized that Microsoft does have good documentation for a beginner like me.

No, because s is not a global object.  It's local to main. and thus will not be destroyed.  If s were declared outside the function, then it would be.

@TimRoberts exit terminates the program immediately (at the OS process level), no destructors will be called (also not for global variables)

It might be worth looking into the difference in behavior between exit() and _exit():  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/exit-exit-exit?view=msvc-170

exit(3) never returns. If you get this, you also get that local objects are not destroyed.

@PepijnKramer You are incorrect.  exit is a runtime library function, and does the global cleanup before calling the OS termination code.  https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/exit/

Re (2) the process is going away, so there can't be memory leaks as the address space will be reclaimed by the OS (also any kernel handles opened by the process).

I feel obliged to start by saying that in real use of C++, this shouldn't be an issue. To make a long story short, calling exit in C++ is almost always a mistake. Most places you'd consider calling exit in C, you should probably throw some exception that will be caught in main, then return from main.
Global objects are cleanly destructed, but local objects are not. For example, this code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

class Foo {
    char const *s;
public:
    Foo(char const *s) : s(s) {}
    ~Foo() { fprintf(stderr, "cleaning up %s object\n", s); }
};

Foo f("global");

int main() {
    Foo g("local");
    exit(0);
}

Produces this output:
cleaning up global object

Live on Godbolt
For any who might wonder about why this is written the way it is/how it works:

Used fprintf instead of std::cerr because when f is being destroyed, we don't know whether std::cerr still exists or not.
All string literals have static storage duration, so when f and g are destroyed, the string literals they attempt to print do both still exist (even though it might sort of seem like the one used by g might be destroyed upon exit from main).

That having been said, after you call exit, you'd normally expect all the resources owned by that process to be reclaimed by the OS (including the stack, heap, and globals) regardless of whether their C++ destructors run.
About the only sort of resources that can be a concern are ones that are actually outside that process. For example, if a process has an open connection to a database or web server, there will often be resources on that server that aren't (immediately) cleaned up. For robustness, most servers will periodically clean up resources that have been open but unused for a long time though.

TLS objects are mentioned in the exit() manual  but missing in the answer. Static (local) objects are also mentioned in the manual but missing in the answer.

@3CxEZiVlQ: I'm not sure what manual you're talking about, but neither of those is mentioned in the question. Unless the OP cares about them, I'd rather not overload the answer with "stuff" they're unlikely to care about.

The question is "What variables are destroyed when calling exit(), based on Microsoft's docs?". You have answered about only a half of cases.

@JerryCoffin, could you add them at the end? I think they would make reading other documentation later on easier but your current answer contains the bulk of what I needed.

Or @3CxEZiVlQ, could you include those in an answer?

@JerryCoffin, is there no order in how objects are destroyed especially the important ones like cout and cerr based on this line you wrote: we don't know whether std::cerr still exists or not.?

@JerryCoffin, with respect to clean up, do we know how quickly the OS would reclaim the resources or how often the database or server would clean up resources?

"open connections" shouldn't be an issue at all. If I'm sending a request to a webserver, then close the connection (which is what happens when the process dies), the webserver knows that nobody is interested in the answer anyway. Likewise, if a connection to a database dies, I cannot imagine the database doing anything other than an automated rollback... allowing the client to reconnect, then somehow link the new connection to the dead old one, then figuring out what the actual state is (i.e. which commands have reached the db)... much too complex.

Here are all examples when objects are destroyed at exit() call.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <thread>

class Foo {
  char const* s;

 public:
  Foo(char const* s) : s(s) {}
  ~Foo() { fprintf(stderr, "cleaning up %s object at %p\n", s, this); }
};

Foo global("global");
thread_local Foo global_tls("global_tls");

void routine() {
  using namespace std::chrono_literals;
  thread_local Foo local_tls("local_tls");
  printf("global_tls: %p\n", &global_tls);
  printf("local_tls: %p\n", &local_tls);
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
}

std::jthread thr_global(routine);

int main() {
  static Foo static_local("static_local");
  Foo local("local");
  std::jthread thr_local(routine);
  std::this_thread::yield();
  exit(0);
}

Possible stderr output:
cleaning up static_local object at 0x58c995731900
cleaning up global_tls object at 0x72b3630ff628
cleaning up local_tls object at 0x72b3630ff630
cleaning up global_tls object at 0x72b3628fe628
cleaning up local_tls object at 0x72b3628fe630
cleaning up global object at 0x58c9957318c0

https://godbolt.org/z/7oKcoad1E

Global (global static) objects are destroyed: global and thr_global.
Local static objects are destroyed: static_local
Local (with automatic storage duration) are not destroyed: local and thr_local.
Thread local variables (globally and locally scoped) are destroyed like static objects, multiplied by amount of threads that use such variables: 2 x global_tls and 2 x local_tls.

Local resources allocated outside of the exited process, like database connections that usually are sockets, are not leaked and freed using other mechanisms. For example, sockets on a server side are notified about closing a connection, or some time or other a server closes an inactive connection.

"are not leaked and freed using other mechanisms." For me, it is a leak, it is not because extra others mechanism exist to do the clean up. Created temporaries files are also resources from my point of view (which were not removed then).
